# I need to create a validation with JS for promotion code

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, frontend

I need to verify if a promotion code is valid when the user add to the form. 
1. need to have 9 characters
2. When multiplying the first number by 9, the second by 8, the third by 7, and so the resulting number should be divisible by 11
3. A single digit may not appear more than twice next to each other

this what I have so far.

```js
let number = ['613884922'];

let sum = 0
strNumber = number.toString();
if (strNumber.length != 9) {
  return false;
}
for (var i = 0; length = strNumber.length; i < 9, i += 1) {
  var n = strNumber.charAt(i);
  sum += n * (length - i);
}
if (sum % 11 != 0) {
  return false;
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing right.

I also need to add that to a form so the user can add the code and see if he/she win

I'm not sure how I can add the code to the form. 
This what I have so far.

```
</head>

<body>

  <div class = user>
    <h1> Hello! </h1>
    <h1> check if you are lucky!</h1>
  </div>

<form>
    <input name="name" placeholder="What is your name?" class="name" required />
    <input name="emailaddress" placeholder="What is your email?" class="email" type="email" required />
    <input name="code" placeholder="Add you code here and good luck!" class="code" type="code" required></input>
    <input name="submit" class="btn" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<script>
  let number = [];

  let sum = 0
  strNumber = number.toString();
    if (strNumber.length != 9) {
    return false;
  }
    for (var i = 0; length = strNumber.length; i < 9, i += 1) {
    var n = strNumber.charAt(i);
    sum += n * (length - i);
  }
    if (sum % 11 != 0) {
    return false;
  }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a loooot

Comment: what do you like to do, if you gor a wrong number or what to do with a right number?

Comment: of course Nina !!! 
wrong number - Not this time 
wright number - Congratulations

Comment: to add the validation code to the form, would I need to "name" the form?
<form name="promocode">
 and then 
var name = document.forms["promocode"]["code"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `check`

- checks the length of the string,
- checks of the string does contain more than three same digits,
- get a sum by splitting the string and add the multiplication of each digit,
- and return the result of the restless division by `11`.

```js
function check(string) {
    if (string.length !== 9) return 'wrong length';
    if (/(\d)\1{2}/.test(string)) return 'too much of the same';
    var sum = Array.from(number).reduce((s, v, i) => s + (9 - i) * v, 0);
    return !(sum % 11);
}


var number = '613884922',
    sum = Array.from(number).reduce((s, v, i) => s + (9 - i) * v, 0);

console.log(check('613884922'));
console.log(check('613384922'));
console.log(check('2'));
console.log(check('2123456789'));
console.log(check('618884922'));
```